# EOFException at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1508)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to run a matrix multiplication example presented by Mr. Norstadt under following link http://www.norstad.org/matrix-multiply/index.html. I can run it successfully with hadoop 0.20.2 but I tried to run it with hadoop 1.0.3 but I am getting following error. Is it the problem with my hadoop configuration or it is compatibility problem in the code which was written in hadoop 0.20 by author.Also please guide me that how can I fix this error in either case. Here is the error I am getting.

```
in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:180)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1486)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1470)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.fillMatrix(TestMatrixMultiply.java:60)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.readMatrix(TestMatrixMultiply.java:87)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.checkAnswer(TestMatrixMultiply.java:112)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.runOneTest(TestMatrixMultiply.java:150)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.testRandom(TestMatrixMultiply.java:278)
        at TestMatrixMultiply.main(TestMatrixMultiply.java:308)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Thanks in advance

Regards,
waqas

Comment: If it makes problems due it can't read the sequencefile header, why don't you regenerate the file? Or just use 20.2?

Comment: Thomas yes ofcourse 20.2 is an option but I wanted to use it with newer version(1.0.3). And if this is all working fine with 20.2 then it means that method for writing or reading sequence files is correct(at least for 20.2). Do you think that there might be difference in support of reading and writing sequence files in 20.2 and 1.0.3?

Comment: This error can only occur if the size of the input file is less than 4 bytes - can you provide the file size of the input file(s) in your original question

Comment: @Chris thanks.. I got the problem. Infact it reads _SUCCEESS file along with others while using FileSystem.listStatus method. Can you please tell me how to filter _SUCCESS files while using listStatus. Thanks

Comment: I see you've answered your own question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817824/filter-log-files-success-and-log-in-filesystem-liststatus, please post an answer linking to that question so as to mark this question as answered, and to help those that stumble across this question in future

Comment: thanks Chris and Thomas for your help.. I wrote it in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it right. Infact it was not filtering _SUCCESS file automatically and due to reading this log file exception mentioned in the question was occuring. I filtered the files and now its working fine. Here is the link how I filtered the files [Filter log files(_success and _log) in FileSystem.liststatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817824/filter-log-files-success-and-log-in-filesystem-liststatus)

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered same problem, in my case it was giving exception because I haven't closed `SequenceFile.Writer` object. Problem got resolved when I added `sequenceFileWriter.close()` statement in my code.

Also if input in *MapReduce* program is output of some previous MapReduce program then you have to explicitly write code to ignore `_SUCCESS` file.

PS: I am using CHD4 Cloudera Hadoop configuration