# Filter log files(_success and _log) in FileSystem.liststatus

Tags: java, filter, hadoop

Hi while using FileSystem.listStatus method, I want to filter log files and list only the files which are not log files. How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the source for [FileInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.3/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.java?view=markup)(line 62) they have a private static PathFilter that ignores files that start with an underscore or period. As its private, you'll have to make a copy of the code, or you're answer is sufficient if your input files always start with part (i.e. you've not used MultipleOutputs)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got rid of _SUCCESS files

```
PathFilter clusterFileFilter = new PathFilter() {
                  public boolean accept(Path path) {
                    return path.getName().startsWith("part");
                  }
                };


    FileStatus[] fileStatusArray = fs.listStatus(path, clusterFileFilter);
```